# Proper way to use FIO (Flexible IO tester) for I/O throughput

Tags: linux

I was testing with the number of jobs and was expecting to get the total I/O throughput for each different number of jobs

The job numbers should have positive correlation with the total I/O throughput

The test I have conducted in the SSD workstation is here below 
The result didnt make any sense because I/O throughput of 1 job is bigger than multiple number of jobs

[FIO Test Result using SSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmuO6.png)

However when I test it in my macbook with the virtual box(with SSD configured),the result is different

[FIO Test Result using Virtual Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyjCy.png)

This is the FIO parameter that I have used in the test

```
   filename=/dev/sdd
    bs=4k
    numjobs=1 ~ 64
    iodepth=32
    direct=1
    ioengine=libaio
    rw=read
    runtime=20
    group_reporting=1
```

Is there something that I have done wrong? 
I believe I have used the parameters wrong on this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer, the reason was the proper way of using the FIO 
if we use the FIO asynchronously then the number of depth should increase and if the FIO is set to synchronous the number of jobs should increase to increase the throughput.

Answer (score 0):

The answer over on [fio -numjobs bigger, the iops will be smaller, the reason is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45910963/fio-numjobs-bigger-the-iops-will-be-smaller-the-reason-is) might have some information applicable here. However as you're using an SSD I'd note your iodepth (32) kinda matches the typical maximum number of SATA commands you can have outstanding. This would mean that you're in the case where your first job already generated the maximum throughput and you're deep into diminishing returns - adding more simultaneous jobs just leads to more queuing, which means more latency. All that extra work that isn't generating a benefit but is chewing up resources which means you aren't submitting the I/O that could be processed as fast and thus performance is past the peek.

Comment: Thanks but that is not the right answer. because I figured it out. actually if I increase the number jobs it should increase the throughput.

Comment: @SunghoHong You're right about being able to submit more sync I/O with more jobs but it also depends on where the bottlenecks are. If my CPU is fast enough to keep up, then submitting I/O asynchronously will be enough to saturate the disk and more threads/processes/depth is diminishing returns. If my CPU can't keep up (my storage is ludicrously fast) then I may need multiple CPUs **and** async I/O before I can saturate it. See https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/6/18/785 for an example where async I/O alone is combined with threads.

Comment: Yes but if you look at the test results I have only assigned one jobs, two jobs, four jobs which is a very little number. So in that case I assume that every CPUs should have the same result. I agree that if the total number of jobs are increase more than 32 we will experience bottlenecks but not in this case

Comment: Because **each** job is actually putting down 32 I/Os concurrently you may actually reach a bottleneck long before. I suspect if each job only had an iodepth of 1 your results would have looked different.

Comment: So you did but wasn't that what my original answer was trying to say - "'you're in the case where your first job already generated the maximum throughput" ? It's just interesting you said that wasn't right but I'm glad you found an answer that works for you :-)